# Predict quantitative response variable from quantitative and qualitative variables

Tags: data-mining

I have to predict a quantitative response variable Y from p quantitative and q qualitative variables. There's around 100,000 rows in the data frame. What predictive methods can I use for that purpose?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What does Y represent, what are some salient p's and q's, and how many are there of each? Give us a flavor of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the regression methods for predicting a quantitative variable. For the qualitative features, you can binarize them to pass to the learning algorithm. If you use Python, scikit-learn provide classes for doing that in the preprocessing module.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, could you give some more details when you're saying "one of the regression methods" ? It would be helpfull for later search.